# Create a JSON Object based on input parameter in MuleSoft DataWeave 2.0

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

So I have a REST API which can have there input Params: START, STOP, RESTART. Start and Stop are distinct operations for the REST API but RESTART essentially means STOP and START. Hence I want to create a Dynamic JSON of either 1 node or 2 nodes based on the operation chosen For e.g. For START/STOP the JSON will be:

```
{ "appID": "1234",
   "operation": "START"}
```

OR

```
{ "appID": "1234",
   "operation": "STOP"}
```

While for RESTART it be be like:

```
{ "appID": "1234","operation": "STOP"},{ "appID": "1234","operation": "START"}
```

I can then loop through this array and call my API once or twice.However I am at a loss to understand how do I create this JSON dynamically in data weave based on the Operation param passed as an input to the REST API call.I have tried to create a variable with 2 node JSON nodes and then try too loop but that doesn't seem to be working.

I tried something like this:

```
var count = 0
var appID = "1234567890"
var op = "START"
---
(operation map ((item, index) -> {
    "appID": appID,
    "operation": if(op=='START' and index == 0) "START"
                 else if(op=='STOP' and index==0) "STOP" 
                 else if(op=='RESTART' and index==0) "STOP" 
                 else if(op=='RESTART' and index==1) "START" 
                 else ''
})) [ 0 to operation.totalcount - count ]
```

where the value of Count is either 0 or 1 based on the operation

Comment: What is `operation` input value? The example outputs are missing brackets. Are they all arrays? What fails with your script? and please use the code sample formatting for code, not blockquote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly if the input value `operation` is "RESTART" then the script should return an array of elements start and stop, if "START" just a start element and if "STOP" just a stop element. I assume the output is always an array.

For this script the variable `op` represents the input. I use the value of op to return the operation if it is not "RESTART". If it is I return "STOP" first and add a second element for "START".

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var appID = "1234567890"
var op = "RESTART"
---
[
    {
        "appID": appID,
        "operation": if(op !='RESTART') op
                    else "STOP" 
    }
] ++ if (op =='RESTART') [{
        "appID": appID,
        "operation": "START" 
    }] else []
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "appID": "1234567890",
    "operation": "STOP"
  },
  {
    "appID": "1234567890",
    "operation": "START"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work perfectly on second thoughts I got rid of RESTART and made it START and STOP where START will always act as RESTART. Thanks for the help.